# Python gspread getting accessNotConfigured - Project (number) is not found and cannot be used for API calls

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-api, gspread

I'm using python 3 and the gspread lib to access a google sheet in the cloud.

Using the **same credentials** (**and same python script run same way**) it works from my computer and it doesn't work from a docker image on the same computer, same credentials. Some times it works using virtualenv (same python version) but now in the docker container I cannot figure out why this is happening. Same credentials json config.

This is the full error I'm getting:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Project is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Drive API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project= then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overvie    w?project="
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Project is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Drive API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found it was a compatibility issue (which is related to the version of the Sheet API in use.

I downgraded gspread version from 3 to 0.6.2 and it works.